# How can I prevent PHP from removing curly brace from json string?

Tags: php, json, post, drupal-8, guzzle

I have a Drupal controller method that does a post using Guzzle. When I use postman, the response is valid json, but when the controller returns the data, it's missing the first curly brace. Am I doing anything obviously wrong?

```
 public function getproject(Request $request)
{
    $client = \Drupal::httpClient();
    $request = $client->post($this->uri, [
        'json' => [
            'projectOrJobNumber'=> $request->query->get('projectNo'),
            'accessCode' => $request->query->get('accessCode')
        ]
    ]);

    $response = $request->getBody(true);
    \Drupal::logger('my_module')->notice($response);
    return $response;
}
```

The log shows the string missing the opening curly brace/bracket. Is there an easy way to fix this?

In the log

```
Message     @"jobs":[{"Address":"Master Services","Contacts":[{"Jo
```

Comment: https://guzzle3.readthedocs.io/http-client/response.html#json-responses

Comment: @Ben, Drupal uses Guzzle 6, so the link you posted above is outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
$request->getBody(true)
```

with

```
$request->getBody()->getContents()
```

I don't know if Drupal wraps Guzzle somehow, but out of the box Guzzle doesn't modify the response. So you should be fine, just use `->getContents()` on the body or convert it to `(string)`.